# What is a reason of match.error?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

```
type Occurrences = List[(Char, Int)]

val lard = List(('a', 1), ('d', 1), ('l', 1), ('r', 1))
val r = List(('r', 1))


def subtract2(x: Occurrences, y: Occurrences): Occurrences =
  x.foldLeft(List[(Char, Int)]())({case (acc, list) if(!(y.contains(list))) => acc.::(list)})

subtract2(lard, r)
```

thrown

```
scala.MatchError: (List(),(a,1)) (of class scala.Tuple2)
at forcomp.A$A183$A$A183$$anonfun$subtract2$1.apply(temp.sc:11)
at forcomp.A$A183$A$A183$$anonfun$subtract2$1.apply(temp.sc:11)
at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(temp.sc:120)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(temp.sc:80)
at forcomp.A$A183$A$A183.subtract2(temp.sc:11)
at #worksheet#.#worksheet#(temp.sc:14)
```

Whats the reason of this error? I suppose, that all problem is in cons, but more exactly i don't know

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [MatchError](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/MatchError.html) is thrown whenever an object doesn't match any pattern of a pattern matching expression.

Usually `foldLeft` expects a fully defined function and what you're giving it is a [partially defined](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/PartialFunction.html) one. In this scenario your argument to fold left should have two cases:

1. case (acc, list) if(!(y.contains(list))
2. case (acc, list) if(y.contains(list))

Answer (score 4):

You get a match error because you are not covering all the cases (i.e. when y.contains(list))

```
def subtract2(x: Occurrences, y: Occurrences): Occurrences =
  x.foldLeft(List[(Char, Int)]()) ({
    case (acc, list) if !(y.contains(list)) => acc.::(list)
    case (acc,list)  => acc})
```

Comment: Why match twice? Once would be sufficient and simpler: `x.foldLeft[Occurrences](List.empty) { (acc, pair) => if (y contains pair) acc else pair :: acc }`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
val lard = List(('a', 1), ('d', 1), ('l', 1), ('r', 1))
val r = List(('r', 1))
lard diff r
```

Comment: your answer solved the technical problem (getting the diff) but doesn't answer the question (why the match failed). Still I +1 you since I think people should be encouraged to answer and not get down voted for trying

Answer (score -1):

I think it's because you didn't specify the start and the rest inside `foldLeft` method. Without specifying `start` element and `rest`, it will always append empty list `List()` and failed the pattern matching (just like in the error log `(List(),(a,1))`). Adding another matching scenario will solve the `MatchError` but might yield the result different from what you imagined.

Try something like that:

```
def subtract2(x: Occurrences, y: Occurrences): Occurrences = 
  x.foldLeft(List[(Char, Int)]){ (start, rest) =>
    start match {
       case (acc, list) => if !(y.contains(list)) => acc.::(rest)
       case _           => handle_other_cases_here
    }
  }
```